# Getting an error in the backend of website tool

Tags: sql

The website tool is connected to a 3 sql views.

For one view the code included contains many parts. For the view -The number of columns has not changed but for the underlying table they have increased.

The Website throws an error when specific data is added. If the data is removed and cache is re-set for the website tool, it works.

Msg 511, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot create a row of size 8111 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Hope the above makes sense? Could anyone please guide me as to what can be done to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you please clarify when you say 'expand your data size' thanks - Website end or the size for the columns

Comment: This looks like SQL Server. Please in future tag the actual type of database (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc.)

Comment: @maSTAShuFu - nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to store too much information on that row. The view doesn't matter, its the table that is trying to store it. I bet the new columns have defaults which is adding to the total amount of data you are storing, pushing you over the limit.

Do you have any varchar(max) fields?

I imagine if you were to put a row of data in there with blank strings etc you would see that succeed.

The long term solution is to either; break the table up into smaller tables, using the view to keep them together, or impose tighter limits on how much information you are putting in there

Comment: Yes, a lot more columns have been added to the underlying table. Most of the columns contain NULL. data types are nvarchar (20) null or float null or nvarchar255. There are no varchar(max).

Comment: If you were to add in a row that had all blank strings, does it work? The issue is that the total number of bits of data you add can't exceed a certain amount. Usually that comes from big strings, but if you have a lot of little bits of information it will all add up

Comment: Your error message is saying that your limit is 8060, but you are trying to put in 8111 worth of data. Its just a width issue. If you were to change your nvarchar's to varchars (assuming you don't need unicode data) that will save you a bit of space

Comment: I tried this- changing from nvarchar to varchar. It did not work.